# Split days of the week string MTWTHFSSU using PREG_SPLIT

Tags: php, regex

I want to split the text 'MTWTHFSSU' days of the week and store it in an array.

So far I am using this code using preg_split and REGEX.

```
$splitdays = preg_split('/(.H?)/',$days,null,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY|PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
print_r($splitdays);

array[0=>M, 1 => T, 2 => W, 3 => TH, 4 => F, 5 => S, 6 => S, 7 => U]
//this is my output
//if i change (.U) i will get correct SUNDAY = 'SU' but TH will be  => T, => H
```

Comment: Try: `preg_split('/(.[HU]?)/',$days,null,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY|PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE)`

Comment: Or this works too: `preg_split('/(.H|.U?)/',$days,null,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY|PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the `.` can match any character.

As an alternative, you can use a bit more precise match with preg_match_all and use a pattern with an alternation `|` to list the more specific matches at the beginning and use a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) to list the single character variations.

```
TH|SU|[MTWFS]
```

For example

```
$days = "MTWTHFSSU";
$pattern = "/TH|SU|[MTWFS]/";
preg_match_all($pattern, $days, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => M
    [1] => T
    [2] => W
    [3] => TH
    [4] => F
    [5] => S
    [6] => SU
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```
$days='MTWTHFSSU';
$splitdays = preg_split('/(.H|.U?)/',$days,null,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY|PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
print_r($splitdays);
```

@anubhava's more concise comment works as well

```
preg_split('/(.[HU]?)/',$days,null,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY|PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE)
```